# Performance implications of unpacking dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a chunk of code that takes a series of variables and passes them to N number of modules.  To simplify readability of code rather than passing the variables over and over again I created a dictionary and unpack that to modules as follows:

```
message_package = {
    'v1' : v1,
    'v2' : v2,
    'v3' : v3
}
for mod in mods:
   mod.f1(**message_package)
[...]
if condition:
   mod.f2(**message_package)
```

Each module then grabs variables they need and ignore the rest:

```
def mod1.f1(v1=None,**kwargs):
   do_something()
```

From a readability/usability standpoint I find this quite nice -- variables are immediately available without having to pull them out of **kwargs, and if I add a variable to the message package it's only one line and I don't have to update all modules.

As I'm somewhat new to Python I'm wondering... is this very unpythonic? Is there a big performance impact from constantly unpacking these dictionaries and/or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is fine (Pythonic), no, there is no huge performance impact. You can measure that kind of thing with the `timeit` module, if you are interested.

Comment: It is Pythonic, and I highly doubt there's any significant performance issue; it would only be if you were doing it a whoooole lot, if at all. That said, don't worry about performance until you have to; readability is more important until you actually have performance issues in your code. And if you do, profile your code to find where you should work on improving performance first; don't just grab for something that might have a more efficient, but possibly less readable version.

Comment: Premature optimization is evil.

Comment: I wouldn't do this if, for example, `v1` is only used by `f1` and `v2, v3` are only used by `f2`. Your sample code is too abstract to tell if this is a good idea or not. (To be clear, my concern is over which values are actually packed up in `message_package`, not over the idea of using a dict to package up related keyword arguments.)

Comment: Performance impact depends on `message_package` size. For the record: if it's size is 30, packing/unpacking is 10 times slower then if you'd pass dict as input arg.

Comment: Even if it's slower, it might be worth it for code maintainability (as well as readability).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments above.  I followed martijn's suggestion and ran a simple test using timeit.

The results using my data are as follows:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('passdict()',setup=setup,number=1000000)
0.1841774140484631
>>> timeit.timeit('unpack()',setup=setup,number=1000000)
0.43643336702371016
>>>
```

Looks like Cyphase was correct that there would only be a performance issue if I were doing this a "whoooole lot" -- unpacking is twice as slow as passing a dictionary, but only costs 250ms over 1M iterations. For me this is negligible as I'm only dealing with 5-10 calls in one function.